# Can I save this Cherry Plum?

Tags: fruit-trees

This is the cherry plum I am trying to save in my new back yard (tree was overgrown with weeds for years and we just moved in an I have been restoring the backyard). Any help or suggestions would be awesome. So far I have not done anything except some pruning. Tree doesn't need the timber brace underneath but I have placed it there while I have been working.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

On the other hand, it makes quite a distinctive feature. A talking point, not the average ornament you'd buy from your local garden centre. I guess it depends on factors such as how much room you have, your emotional attachment to the tree and your overall plans for the garden.

Answer (score 0):

If you're clearing a new garden and you  want to plant other things,to be quite honest,I'd have the tree removed. It's only a matter of time till rain penetrating the fractured stump causes rot to occur (if it  hasn't started already) and when it does, you may find the bough that is arcing off to one side  suddenly falls. Sad though it may be, I'd recommend removing  it and having the stump bored out to a depth of 12-18 inches, which should take care of any large roots left behind.

Comment: i thought as much but was hoping to try a few methods before removing. If necessary I have a fig tree I would gladly replace it with. But i will try first. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

1. Cut cleanly the part that I marked with red color in the photo so that the remaining surface is flat, but not horizontal, it should make rain go *away* from the tree (meaning from the trunk that is still alive).

[image]

2. Remove the leaves that are most damaged.
3. (optional) Hang some bird feeder, bird bath or similar ornament somewhere in the tree.
4. Leave everything to Mother Nature.